# How to send a file to a mocked Axios response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, jestjs

I am writing unit tests for an API call I'm making in my Vue component. Now one of the API calls sends returns a file which the component relies on for conditional rendering.

The error I am getting now is that Jest is not able to parse the file.

This is my most recent approach:

```
import testPdf from '../files/test-pdf.pdf';

export const getDocumentBlob = {
  data: {
    file: new Blob([testPdf], { type: 'application/pdf' }),
  },
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {},
  config: {},
};
```

The object is then loaded into an array which is mapped over to mock a variety of Axios responses. That all works.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: import is for modules. For arbitrary files in Node use `fs`. It's unclear why you need a real pdf here

Comment: You wouldn't respond with a blob embedded in JSON. What response format does the test subject expect and what does it do with the response data?

Comment: The backend is responding with multipart/form-data. The file is a binary string. I'm just not sure how to mock this. Ideally I wouldn't be using a real PDF, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is not a common response format and I don't think Axios handles it very well if at all. If the only data is the file, why not respond with an array buffer or octet stream? And again, what does the test subject do with the response? Please [edit] your question to include some example code